# Recursive to Iterative in Java

Tags: java, recursion, iteration, enumeration

I'm trying to convert this recursive method to an iterative method. But I am stuck in the middle.

```
static void string_recurse(String active,String rest) {
  if (rest.length() == 0) {
    System.out.println(active);
  } else {
    string_recurse(active + rest.charAt(0), rest.substring(1, rest.length()));
    string_recurse(active, rest.substring(1, rest.length()));
  }
}
```

I can't understand how to convert this recursive method to an iterative one.
What this method does is it prints all "subset" words of a given word. More formally, if we have the string `s_1s_2...s_n` it enumerates all strings `s_{i1}s_{i2}...s_{ik}` such that `i1, i2, ..., ik` is a subset of `{1, ..., n}` and `i1 < i2 < ... < ik`

For example when we call `string_recurse("","abc");` we get the output:

```
abc
ab
ac
a
bc
b
c
(the empty word)
```

Comment: Can you tell what this method do ?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?! Amazingly, I don't even see a loop here.

Comment: what is the active and rest strings ?? can you show some example?

Comment: this method prints combinations of a input string.
string_recurse("","abc");

abc

ab

ac

a

bc

b

c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Main {

    static void string_recurse(String active,String rest) {
        if (rest.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println(active);
        } else {
            string_recurse(active + rest.charAt(0), rest.substring(1, rest.length()));
            string_recurse(active, rest.substring(1, rest.length()));
        }
    }

    static void string_iterative(String s) {
        int n = s.length();
        for (int mask = (1 << n) - 1; mask >= 0; mask--) {
            String temp = "";
            for (int pos = 0; pos < n; pos++)
                if (((1 << (n - 1 - pos)) & mask) != 0)
                    temp += s.charAt(pos);
            System.out.println(temp);               
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abcd";
        string_recurse("", s);
        string_iterative(s);
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you know that your string's length never goes over `32` use this iterative method. If you know that the string's length goes over `32` but is bounded by `64` define `mask` as `long`. If the length can be more than `64` stick with the original recursive method.

The idea of this iterative method is to map every character of the string to either `1` or `0`. `1` means that the corresponding character takes part in the current sub-word and `0` means the opposite. So to loop over all "subset words" we just need to loop from `00..0 (n bits)` to `11..1(n bits)`. This can be done just by looping over the integer range [`0`, `2^n - 1`] and by using the binary representation of the numbers. Note that in the given example those numbers are looped over in reverse fashion in order for the iterative function to be consistent with the recursive one.